# React hook, variable not captured in callback

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

From my understanding, the function Design executed every time when setRenderer called; and a new SyncEvent created each time. However the variable not captured in eventRef.subscribe('properties'...). Why renderer in the callback is null, but it does have a value in function body?

```
export class SyncEvent {
    subscriber: (value: any) => void;
    subscribers = new Map<string, ((value: any) => void)[]>();

    subscribe(id: string, callback: (value: any) => void) {        ;
        this.subscribers.set(id, [...this.subscribers.get(id) || [], callback]);
    }

    unsubscribe(id: string) {
        this.subscribers.delete(id);
    }

    emit(id:string, value?: any) {
        this.subscriber && this.subscriber(value);
        this.subscribers.get(id)?.forEach(s => s(value));
    }
}

const Design = (props: Props) => {
  const eventRef = new SyncEvent();
  const [renderer, setRenderer] = useState<ViewRenderer>()
  const [manager] = useState(new ViewRenderer({component: PageView, isContainer: true}, eventRef))

  console.log(renderer);  // not null when 2nd runs
  console.log(eventRef)

  eventRef.subscribe('properties', (event) => {
    console.log(renderer) // <--- renderer is NULL      
    setRenderer(renderer);
  })

  return (
    <div className='design'>
      <div className='design-main'>
        {manager.renderComponent()}
      </div>
      <div className='design-right'>
        <PropertiesViewPanel properties={properties}/>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are creating subscription directly in the render method and you aren't cleaning the subscription on a re-render. Due to this the old registered subscription with a old closure value is still run since you have only assigned the manager instance once in setState

You should use useEffect to setup and clean subscriptions

```
const Design = (props: Props) => {

  const [renderer, setRenderer] = useState<ViewRenderer>()
  const [manager, setManager] = useState(null)
  useEffect(() => {
     const eventRef = new SyncEvent();
     setManager(new ViewRenderer({component: PageView, isContainer: true}, eventRef));
     eventRef.subscribe('properties', (event) => {   
         setRenderer(renderer);
     });

     return () => {
        eventRef.unsubscribe('properties');
     }
  }, [renderer]);

  return (
    <div className='design'>
      <div className='design-main'>
        {manager && manager.renderComponent()}
      </div>
      <div className='design-right'>
        <PropertiesViewPanel properties={properties}/>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: I should notice I have passed eventRef to manager, and the manager only created once and holds the reference of eventRef. Thanks a lot, while in debuging, my mind easily goes narrowed.